# Pandas column indexing for searching?

Tags: python, mysql, performance, pandas, indexing

In relational database, we can create index on columns to speed up querying and joining on those columns. I want to do them same thing on pandas dataframe. The row index seems not what relational database offers.

The question is: Are columns in pandas indexed for searching by default?

If not, is it possible to index columns manually and how to do it?

Edit: I have read pandas docs and searched everywhere, but no one mentions indexing and searching/merging performance on pandas. Seem no one care about this issue, although it is critical in relational database. Can any one make a statement about indexing and performance on pandas?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really, pandas model is not that of an in-memory relational database. You can check out 'indexing' and 'multi-indexing' in the docs to see your options but fundamentally, pandas is not an RDBMS with 'declarative data navigation' facilities.

Comment: Does it mean Pandas provide columns indexing in form of 'indexing' and 'multi-indexing'? I have read the docs but it's still not clear. Can you please make an example of how to speed up querying/joining using 'indexing' and 'multi-indexing'?

Comment: In pandas, you can declare any column or combination of columns as an index (or multiindex). This is not required either for searching or for merging. Sorting by index is not faster than sorting by a regular column. (Just checked experimentally.)

Comment: It is not required but index will make the searching/merging much faster as on relational database.

Comment: I said "in pandas".

Comment: No, it does not mean pandas really provides 'indexing' in the RDBMS sense you're using it. Because pandas is not an rdbms. If you have a specific question about data manipulation in pandas and performance problems you're encountering, you should ask that.

Comment: I had a 'too' specific question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627472/are-columns-in-pandas-indexed-for-searching) that seems no one can help and I ended up giving up pandas, using manually built dictionary. If I encounter another question not too broad and not too specific, I will ask again.

Comment: Could you make an answer with a statement about relationship between indexing and performance on pandas?

Comment: I don't think that question is 'too specific', it just wasn't very well formulated. You should try to build an [MCVE] to demonstrate the problems you're encountering. It's not difficult to run into performance quirks with pandas when doing non-trivial manipulation, merges, etc. Ask about those, when you encounter them. The answer to 'can I make pandas behave like an RDBMS' is pretty much 'no'.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try to update that question.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @pvg - The pandas model is not that of an in memory relational databases. So, it won't help us much if we try to analogize pandas in terms of sql and it's idiosyncracies. Instead, let's look at the problem fundamentally - you're effectively trying to speed up column lookups/ joins.

You can speed up joins considerably by **setting the column you wish to join by as the index in *both dataframes*** (left and right dataframes that you wish to join) and then **sorting both the indexes**.

Here's an example to show you the kind of speed up you can get when joining on sorted indexes:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint

# Creating DATAFRAME #1
columns1 = ['column_1', 'column_2']
rows_df_1 = []

# generate 500 rows
# each element is a number between 0 and 100
for i in range(0,500):
    row = [randint(0,100) for x in range(0, 2)]
    rows_df_1.append(row)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows_df_1)
df1.columns = columns1

print(df1.head())
```

The first dataframe looks like this:

```
Out[]:    

column_1  column_2
0        83        66
1        91        12
2        49         0
3        26        75
4        84        60
```

Let's create the second dataframe:

```
columns2 = ['column_3', 'column_4']
rows_df_2 = []
# generate 500 rows
# each element is a number between 0 and 100
for i in range(0,500):
    row = [randint(0,100) for x in range(0, 2)]
    rows_df_2.append(row)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows_df_1)
df2.columns = columns2
```

The second dataframe looks like this:

```
Out[]:    

   column_3  column_4
0        19        26
1        78        44
2        44        43
3        95        47
4        48        59
```

Now let's say you wish to join these two dataframes on `column_1 == column_3`

```
# setting the join columns as indexes for each dataframe
df1 = df1.set_index('column_1')
df2 = df2.set_index('column_3')


# joining
%time
df1.join(df2)

Out[]:
CPU times: user 4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 4 ms
Wall time: 46 ms
```

As you can see, just setting the join columns as dataframe indexes and joining after - takes around 46 milliseconds. Now, let's try joining **after sorting the indexes**

```
# sorting indexes
df1 = df1.sort_index()
df2 = df2.sort_index()

Out[]:

CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 9.78 µs
```

This takes around 9.78 µs, much much faster.

I believe you can apply the same sorting technique to pandas columns - sort the columns lexicographically and modify the dataframe. I haven't tested the code below, but something like this should give you a speedup on column lookups:

```
import numpy as np
# Lets assume df is a dataframe with thousands of columns
df = read_csv('csv_file.csv')
columns = np.sort(df.columns)

df = df[columns]
```

Now column lookups should be much faster - would be great if someone could test this out on a dataframe with a thousand of columns

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. On my computer it took 33 us and 11 us for unsorted and sorted index respectively, that is less dramatically than on your computer. Actually I am still very confused on the topic pandas performance tuning. Seems there is no good document around.